# Adding existing maven project to Maven multi module project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, multi-module

I already have an existing maven project in my eclipse workspace. I created another multi module maven project and need to add that existing project as a module. So lets say i have parent project ( my-parent-project) and need to add already existing ( my-maven-project) as a module of that parent project. Can you please help me to do that? I know how to create and add a module project but do not know how to add an existing project as a module.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is something sophisticated. I would just copy/paste the project to a subdirectory and then adjust the parent POM.

Comment: Maven build does not recognize that project as a module even though you adjusted the pom.

Comment: That is true: You need to add it as a module as well in the module/parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are for when the sources are nested and then you just need a modules-module section in your pin

Otherwise it is a dependency (and eclipse is smart enough to resolve these across projects)